# C file will not compile

Tags: c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have a small swift project in XCode 6.2 on OS X 10.10, and to that project was added a small C file, simplified to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void function1(unsigned char buf) {}
unsigned char abuf;
function1(abuf);
```

I cannot get any version of a C file to compile. The specific code above generates 2 errors: "Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'", and "A parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition"

My assumption is that the project is somehow not setup right to compile a C file, but I cannot figure out what is missing. (Note that ultimately the C file is going to be used to access an external library and a "project-Bridging-Header.h" file, currently empty, has been generated.) Can anyone help?

Comment: Function call like `function1(abuf);` have to be in some function.

Comment: Try to compile a *valid* C source.

Comment: What is this: `void function1(unsigned char buf) {}` ?!

Comment: MikeCat - are you suggesting that the function call has to be in a main() equivalent (which there wouldn't be in a swift project) - looks like I've been doing too much javascript lately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not valid C, that's why it doesn't compile. It has nothing to do with Swift whatsoever. You declare a function, you declare an extern variable, and then, out of nowhere, comes what looks like a function call.

In C, code can only be part of a function implementation.